What's the point, if any, of having ear plugs that go beyond the ear canal?
Example of a pair of ear plugs that go beyond the ear canal:

The red arrows designate the part that goes beyond on the ear canal (it covers the concha). Is there any point in it? Eg, does it increase the noise reduction?
By contrast here is a pair of earplugs that only covers the ear canal:

And here is a comparison of three pairs of earplugs with a varying degrees of size:


I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be about music practice or theory.

I have two guesses: 1) to give you something to grab to be able to pull it out (how do you even remove ones that don't stick out some?) 2) to increase the NRR

@ToddWilcox thanks 1) the ear is quite flexible, no pb to remove them. 2) does it increase the NRR?

@FranckDernoncourt I've to go with Andy: while your question may be interesting, it has nothing to do with music practice/theory. I realize this may be a slightly gray area, but this is controversially so specific that it makes it too broad. That said: 1. maybe your ears allow that and you're used to it; ear shapes are very different, differently shaped plugs may allow easier removal or more stable positioning (especially if the musician moves a lot, or the pairing of their sweating/movement can't ensure stable positioning); 2. related to 1., more stable positioning improves NR quality.

@musicamante thanks, https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health: "Questions about how playing or listening to music affects a person's mental or physical condition or vice versa". The question fits that topic. 2 (stable positioning) seems to draw a consensus from my readings so far: same NR if all these earplugs are well-positioned but the small ones can be more easily badly positioned.

@FranckDernoncourt Let's agree to disagree. Still, the very name of that tag refers to aspects that permanently or temporarily (in an obvious relative context) affect mental/physical conditions. You're not asking if any of that plugs have those effects (hearing damages, auricle aches, etc.), you're asking what's the point of one or the other, which mainly affects how stable the positioning may be or how effective they may be in the listening experience, not how "dangerous" any of them may be. If you're worried about those implications, then clarify that importance in your question.

I guess my point is that, while musicians have an inherent interest in hearing health, this is about hearing health. Seems like a better fit on some medical SE if such exists. I don't know that there's anybody here with informed answers on ear physiology.

Some interesting answers I got on Reddit:


verdant_hippie: Better retention and fit, which can help with noise reduction
ashleeh92: Mandibular movement can’t cause seals to break in canal styles. Have full concha bowl and helix lock can keep it in place during jaw movements
droid_mike: Reduces the sound coming from skull vibrations and the "booming" sound of your own voice. It is the only kind of earplugs useful to brass and woodwind players, as the noise from their musical instruments vibrate through their skulls. Short earplugs can actually increase the volume of those instruments into the middle ear. [I am] taking about the long earplugs that go past the first turn in the ear canal. The extra length helps reduce skull noise and voice booming. The ones you posted are not long enough to do that.


tldr: better retention, better fit, reduced skull vibrations (the latter to be confirmed).
It's a mixture of DSP.SE, Medical.SE, Music.SE, and Physics.SE.

Is droid_mike talking about how far the earplugs go into the ear canal, not how far they extend outside it?
